# eth_SendTransaction - Unknown Account

Tags: ethereum

I am trying to send a transaction to an Ethereum node, but keep getting back:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"unknown account"}}
```

Here's my CURL request:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params": [{
"from": "0x73be29b5bbebfa0ba55644e0572999c61fe202b0",
"to": "0x86eeea52041d30cdd3470f320da23f3f08f37d40",
"gas": "0x76c0",
"gasPrice": "0x9184e72a000",
"value": "0x9184e72a",
 "data": "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"
 }],"id":1}' http://the_ether_node.com:8545
```

Do I somehow have to let the master node `know` about the from address?

Which account is it complaining about?

Answer (score 0):

ah! I just realised its because I'm asking the remote server to send eth from an account that only the local knows about!